# How to create panel with title in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Good Evening, please could any one experienced with primefaces tell me how to make a pnel like the one below, i want to make that panel and embed an `<p:imageSwitch>` inside it, is that is possible? if not, how to wrap an `imageSwitch` inside something like this ?, here's the actual panel that i want to create one similar to it:

Note: i tried `<p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Basic Dialog"/>` but i think that its different from the one in the image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you want to use [`<p:panel>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel.jsf) with `<f:facet name="header">` nested like this:

```
<p:panel ...>
    <f:facet name="header" >
        <p:graphicImage ...>
    </f:facet>
    <p:imageSwitch ...>
</p:panel>
```

This way you'll have a panel with a custom header and, of course, custom content like `<p:imageSwitch>`.

If you want, you can nest such panel within a `<p:dialog>` as well.